# 2x2 double piston extender

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am currently working on my modern house, which has a staircase looking like the picture below

It is about 10 Blocks wide, each step upwards is 2 blocks wide and only elevate the player by 0.5 block (slabs).

I am struggling to come up with a design to make part of my stairs shift down into my floor and change into a staircase which still uses slabs going downwards.
So basically instead of a 10 wide staircase going upwards I want a two block wide section of it to "fall down" and reveal stairs going down.

Here is how i amagine it looking:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

I do feel like I would need a 2x2 or even 2x3 set of double piston extenders to get my 2 blocks whide pathway downwards.

Is there any redstone enthusiast out there which can help me with a tileable extender for example which I can stack in this 2x3 grid?

Screenshots of the basic components would be enough, when get home in a few hours I hopefully have the time to show you what I need in pictures.

Comment: A screenshot would be nice to see the currently existing staircase. Could you provide us with something like that?

Comment: As stated above i will provide one once i get home.
But i edit the post to maybe make i more clear.

Comment: Isn't your "ts ts bs bs" pattern meant to say "ts bs ts bs"? Also, did you search for things like "tileable double piston extender"? I am certain that I saw one going up before and probably saw some going sideways as well, so there are probably already designs out there.

Comment: @FabianRöling i have tried that, but I only found designes from way back which don't work in 1.14.4

Comment: Maybe they can be updated to work again. Which ones did you find/try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my prayers. a bit more complex than i imagined but i works none the less
[image: Double piston extender]
This little new friend of mine does the trick. 2 of them next to each other and another set of 2 on the other side and i had my 4 blocks going down. After that all i needed was a monostable running into another 2x2 single poston extender to make a long enough stairway.